# How can I clean up horizontal scaling of an ellipse in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a page where I'm trying to render a circle on an HTML canvas that's got a scale factor applied along the X-axis.  So, I'm rendering an ellipse, with the width divided by the applied scaling factor.  The problem is that the resulting ellipse is pretty ugly (on the left is what I want, items on the right are what I get depending on how heavily scaled the axis is):

[image: On the left, a nice clean circle; two increasingly distorted circles on the right]

I can imagine this is due to some combination of floating-point math, aliasing, etc.  But: how do I fix/work around this?

(If you're wondering, my use case is adding a fixed-pixel-size marker over smaller items on the canvas to increase their visibility; the scale factor applied here is due to user zooming.)

Example canvas code:

```
const ellipseSize = 8;
context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)";
context.strokeWidth = 2;
context.beginPath();
context.ellipse(15, 15, ellipseSize, ellipseSize, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();

let scale = 4.687;
context.scale(scale, 1);
context.lineWidth = 2 / scale;
context.beginPath();
context.ellipse(25, 15, ellipseSize / scale, ellipseSize, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

scale = 8.262;
context.scale(scale, 1);
context.lineWidth = 2 / scale;
context.beginPath();
context.ellipse(25, 15, ellipseSize / scale, ellipseSize, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
```

StackBlitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nycwje

Comment: Could you check out the StackBlitz link? it's not working for me

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: StackBlitz updated.  relevant code added.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

While I'd still be curious if someone else has a better answer that doesn't involve rescaling: the obvious workaround in my case was to un-scale, draw the circle, then re-scale to leave the context how it was.

```
scale = 8.262;
context.scale(scale, 1);
context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)";
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
context.strokeWidth = 2 / scale;
context.beginPath();
context.ellipse(25, 15, ellipseSize / scale, ellipseSize, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();

context.scale(1/scale, 1);
context.beginPath();
context.ellipse(25 * scale, 15, ellipseSize, ellipseSize, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
context.scale(scale, 1);
```

The above draws a perfect blue circular border around the filled red circle.